# Can I add a password hint to an encrypted disk image?

Tags: encryption, dmg

I've got an encrypted dmg. Can I set a password hint for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible currently. You can put such information in the Spotlight comments accessible from Get Info in Finder.