# How do I get the password hint for an encrypted disk?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, security, encryption, filevault

I created an encrypted disk on a USB drive the other day, and added a password hint. I don't remember what the password is. (I have a scheme for mapping hints to passwords, so when there's a hint available I just pick something random and write out the appropriate hint.)

When reconnecting the disk today, OS X popped up the password prompt - but no hint displayed.

When I go into Disk Utility and try to mount the volume, same thing. Not even a button to show the hint!

So now I've got no idea what the password is. How do I find out the hint?

OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)

---

Here's the process I went through. (I went through it again using a spare SD card and took screen grabs at each point.)

1. From Disk Utility, select disk in question and go to the Erase option. Select `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)`

[image]

2. The password box appears. Enter password and add a hint.

[image]

(I usually pick a more cryptic hint than that)

3. Click `Choose`, then click `Erase`, and it will do its thing. Click `Done` once it's done, and quit Disk Utility.

[image]

4. Eject the newly-mounted encrypted disk image from Finder, then unplug USB hard drive.
5. Reinsert USB hard drive and wait for password dialog to appear.

[image]

But where's the hint?!

Comment: Excellent edits  - I was mistakenly thinking of [encrypted disk images - DMG / IMG and such](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284816/can-i-add-a-password-hint-to-an-encrypted-disk-image) on my deleted comment - not whole disk encryption as you’ve clarified.

Comment: Yes - and entering wrong passwords don't seem to show the hint that was saved. I'm sure there used to be a `Show Hint` button, that you could click to get the hint.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve either fallen into a trap or stumbled over a bug. Neither would be comfortable.

Comment: I note that `diskutil` has no obvious options for password hint when you're encrypting a disk. So I wonder what Disk Utility actually even does with the text you enter. Will look through the programming docs later and see if I can find any more clues...

Comment: I have encrypted USB disks since at least Lion and don't think I have ever seen the hint or any way to display it, although I've had no reason to look for it.

Comment: Apparently on 10.13.0 the hint is a little too specific and clear. https://medium.com/@matheusmariano/new-macos-high-sierra-vulnerability-exposes-the-password-of-an-encrypted-apfs-container-b4f2f5326e79

Comment: On the login screen the hint doesn't appear until you enter a password incorrectly.  Have you tried intentionally inputting the wrong password a couple of times?

Comment: Yes, and to no avail. But I'm pretty sure in previous revisions of the OS the `Show Hint` button was always visible, as per the screen shot at the top here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/25/password-protect-external-drive-mac-encrypted-partition/

Comment: This is unlikely to make the hint display, but it may be worthwhile enabling *Show password hints* in *System Preferences --> Login Options* if you haven't already.

Comment: @mjturner thanks for the suggestion, but as you suppose it does make no difference.

Comment: This might be a stupid idea, but it has at least twice helped when a macOS button that used to be there no longer isn't - have you tried holding Option(Alt) when the window is displayed?

Comment: I'm sure you have, but have you tried inputting wrong passwords three times in a row? The Mac login screen, at least, doesn't show the hint until after the third wrong guess.

Comment: @ilmari pressing Option does nothing.

Comment: @Calion yes I have - please see the posted answer along these lines and my comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried entering an incorrect password? If I enter a wrong password three times, I get the hint displayed.

Comment: I have tried this, but the comment I added at the time maybe doesn't make this super-clear. Anyway: yes I have, and I don't get a hint. (I tried entering the wrong password a lot more than three times.)

Comment: Sorry, I did replicate this, but I did it with an encrypted DMG, not with an external drive. Hmm. This seems odd and might be worth contacting Apple.

Comment: Not long after posting this question, I used the Contact Apple thingy to file a report, along with a link to this question. I expected nothing from this, and Apple have met my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help:

1. **Unmount** your encrypted volume.

[image: Disk Utility Unmount Disk]

2. **Mount** back.

(If the password is not stored in your Keychain, it will ask you for the pass in a dialog box and will display a button called "Show Hint")

[image: Show Hint Button]

3. **Press the Button** Show Hint

[image: Hint Revealed]

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65 at least), you can find the hint back when you use `APFS` file system with `(Case-Sensitive, Encrypted)` options

Comment: Can you confirm that this works for you with a drive encrypted with Disk Utility, rather than a disk image? I have the same problem and am at a loss about what to do!

Comment: Please provide step by step instructions, e.g., with images - this answer is, as provided, not at all clear to me.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have any older Macs? You could try mounting it on an older Mac OS. As is often the case with Apple, features that have disappeared still work on older OSes.

Comment: I have the same problem and went to the Apple Store, where I connected the drive to a Mac running a Virtual Machine of 10.10, the earliest they had. The hint did not show.